# GtkBuilder and "names"

Tags: c, gtk, gtkbuilder

I've been trying to get the "names" of all GtkWidgets in a GtkBuilder object.

I've managed to get all objects from the builder object via `gtk_builder_get_objects()` and store them in a GSList.

However, when I use `gtk_widget_get_name()` on the gobjects (which i cast to GtkWidgets), I get generic names such as "GtkWindow" and "GtkButton" instead of "window1" or "button1" that are displayed in glade.

Any help would be ***extremely*** appreciated and would make this programmer ***very*** happy.

Comment: Here's the same question for Python with GObject introspection: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15393120/247696

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The names set for the builder are not the same as name of the `GtkWidget`. `GtkBuilder` maintains an internal hash table which has the name set in `GtkBuilder UI definitions` from the file or string (from which builder was added) and associated object. It is used to retrieve the objects when `gtk_builder_get_object ()` is called. Make use of the [`"name"`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--name) property of `GtkWidget`. Set `"name"` property in the `GtkBuilder UI definitions` to set the name of the `GtkWidget` which can be retrieved using `gtk_widget_get_name()`.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. I mean this, THANK YOU. Off-topic: The gtkbuilder page didn't say or emphasize on the fact that there are two separate "name" properties. Do you know where I can get better information regarding glade and gtkbuilder?

Comment: @seininn: You are welcome! Well [`GTkBuilder` page](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkBuilder.html) never says that name is the set is the property of the associated `GtkWidget`.  It says that its the name assigned to them in UI description. So the property `"name"` associated with `GtkWidget` is not the one being set but it an identifier. I think you got it mixed up :) ... I think online documentations & forums are the best resources I can think of for `glade` & `GtkBuilder`

Answer (score 5):

I am doing the exact same thing. I was able to get the `id=` strings from the `.glade` file using 
`gtk_buildable_get_name()` as specified [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkBuilder.html#BUILDER-UI).

**Note**: Prior to 2.20, GtkBuilder was setting the "name" property of constructed widgets to the "id" attribute. In GTK+ 2.20 or newer, you have to use `gtk_buildable_get_name()` instead of `gtk_widget_get_name()` to obtain the "id", or set the "name" property in your UI definition.

Comment: Note to those using Perl: $widget->get_name() calls gtk_widget_get_name().  To call gtk_buildable_get_name(), use: $name = Gtk3::Buildable::get_name($widget)