# How can I retrieve from a GTK Builder the name of an object?

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

How do I get the name of a Gtk.Widget retrieved from a Builder object?

I specifically mean the name seen in Glade (eg: `button1`), not the name of the class (`GtkWindow`).

This question is exactly the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263756/gtkbuilder-and-names), but for Python with GObject introspection.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the `get_name` method inherited from `Gtk.Widget`. Instead, you have to use the `get_name` method defined in `Gtk.Buildable`, like this:

```python
button = builder.get_object("button1")
print(Gtk.Buildable.get_name(button)) # prints "button1"
```